# How to merge array and sum up the values depending on key?

Tags: php

I have an array something like below. I want to merge the nested array and display the totals. Here ID = 60.I want to merge this [0] and [1] depending in the ID value i.e., 60.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 60
        [TOTAL] => 500
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 60
        [TOTAL] => 600
    )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 61
        [TOTAL] => 600
    )

   )
```

I tried with two for loops

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    foreach($result as $key1 => $value1){
    // Do stuffs here
    }
}
```

I want the output as

```
Array(
     [0] => Array(
           [ID] =>60
           [TOTAL] => 1100
     )
     [1] =>Array(
           [ID] =>61
           [TOTAL] => 600
     )
  )
```

Comment: Quick question: Do you get this array from a database query?

Comment: @vivek_23 No, I get this by merging two arrays. Used array_merge() function and got this

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$result = Array(
     Array
    (
        'ID' => 60,
        'TOTAL' => 500
    ),
    Array
    (
        'ID' => 60,
        'TOTAL' => 600
    ),
   Array
    (
        'ID' => 61,
        'TOTAL' => 600
    )
   );

$set = [];   


foreach($result as $data){
    if(!isset($set[$data['ID']])) $set[$data['ID']] = 0;
    $set[$data['ID']] += $data['TOTAL'];
}

$result_set = [];

foreach($set as $id => $total){
    $result_set[] = [
        'ID' => $id,
        'TOTAL' => $total
    ];
}

print_r($result_set);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/NMmHC

- We store IDs as keys in our `$set` array and keep adding the total to it whenever we come across the same key in the foreach loop.
- In the end, we collect the results in a new array with ID and it's respective total.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [**array_reduce()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) which iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function.

```
$arr = [['ID' => 60,'TOTAL' => 500],['ID' => 60,'TOTAL' => 600],['ID' => 61,'TOTAL' => 600]];

$arr = array_reduce($arr, function($acc, $new) {
    if (!isset($acc[$new['ID']])) {
        $acc[$new['ID']] = $new;
        return $acc;
    }

    $acc[$new['ID']]['TOTAL'] += $new['TOTAL'];
    return $acc;
}, []);

echo '<pre>', print_r(array_values($arr));
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/I5J4f).

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1

```
$arrayvariable=Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 60
        [TOTAL] => 500
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 60
        [TOTAL] => 600
    )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 61
        [TOTAL] => 600
    )
   )
$output = array_reduce($arrayvariable, function (array $compare, array $item) {
        $intrestkey = $item ['ID'];
        if (array_key_exists($intrestkey, $compare)) {
            $compare [$intrestkey] ['TOTAL'] += $item ['TOTAL'];
        } else {
            $compare [$intrestkey] = $item;
        }
        return $compare;
    }, array());

 $incremetedmerged_array = array_values($output);
```

---

```
print_r($incremetedmerged_array); //Produces

Array(
     [0] => Array(
           [ID] =>60
           [TOTAL] => 1100
     )
     [1] =>Array(
           [ID] =>61
           [TOTAL] => 600
     )
  )
```